# HOW TO SHOOT LARGE CARPETS

Tags: panorama, camera-recommendation

WE are planning to shoot LARGE SIZE CARPETS ( 5m /10 m ) with High Quality Resolution for professional Usage , ( LARGE PRINTING , MUSEUM CONSERVATION..ect )
Please can you advise the best camera  , Lenses and Required Lighting. we want to build a studio to take high quality images of  CARPET / RUGS.

few people suggest me to use  " Gig Pan " ..

i need your valuable suggestions to choose the right equipment.

with best regards

Comment: Can you please be specific as to the end use of your project?  Originally, when you asked this the first time, you seemed to imply product photography - now you say this is for museum conservation.   Which is it?  Or, is this a project you won from a free lance site and now you need to figure out how to accomplish this?  If you can be clear how the end user will be using the images, we can better help you.

Comment: Please improve the question you've already asked rather than asking a "new" one on the same topic.

Comment: I am replying to B Shaw , we are basically events & Exhibition organizing company. we have a project , we need to shoot the Large Rugs , since they want to use for multipurpose.they want high quality images. may they use for large printing and and they wants to save the capture the artwork on the rugs..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion maybe will be a little bit strage, but will provide very good quality of images. For camera I will suggest fullframe body like Canon 6D, 5D M3. For lens will propose tild-shift 24 mm Canon lens. Combine this with tripod and shutter release cable. Process is sample: shift to the left the lens, shoot, shift to center, shoot, shift to right, shoot. Open images in software (Photoshop, Hudin) and combine them to panorama. Do not forget to apply lens corrections in the software to avoid distortions. Do not forget some details as X-Rite ColorChecker Passport to adjust the colours.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , what about lighting ? we can not hang the rugs to wall, so we have to keep the rugs on ground and need to take the picture from top views.. since the rug size are very large  5m x 10 and 10m x 10m.. so please advise me the best way to take the high quality images.

Comment: Mohammed, if the carpets will be on the ground will make the things quite complicated. You should find some construction, which permit you to shoot strait down. And you can create line by line photos and combine them. About the light: I am afraid you can't easy light entire carpet with even light. So you can attach 2 or 3 umbrellas on the construction, point them down (or up, to use reflection from the roof) to make as even as possible and move them with the camera

Comment: @romeo can we also do this without a tilt-shift lens ? we can just turn the tripod head to shoot 4 photos , stitch them in photoshop and then do distortion correction

Comment: @Janas, yes, you can. But you will loose some details and precise forms and shapes

Comment: @romeo thanks. I didn't think of that